# Is this relationship between Mandelbrot bulbs a coincidence?

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions, fractals

I was messing around with the Mandelbrot boundaries on Desmos and came across something interesting, and I don't have enough experience with the math behind this to conclude whether it's a coincidence or not.

In the image below, here is what's going on (my apologies if the terms I use aren't correct, please feel free to correct):

- The black lines plot the boundaries of the period 1 and 2 components of the Mandelbrot Set (I'm only concerned with the cardioid at the moment)
- The red line plots a line through the individual two components of the equation of the boundary of the cardioid, defined as$$\frac {e^{it}}{2} - \frac {e^{2it}}{4}$$ (Note that the line, going through the points *e^(it)/2* and -*e^(2it)/4*, is extended to an arbitrary amount that I defined)
- I have a slider for the parameter *t*, which the orange dot plots the respective point on the cardioid (currently set to *t =* */4* - at the base of the 1/4 bulb)
- The blue line represents the vector between the two components (*e^(it)/2* and -*e^(2it)/4*)

As seen in the image, the line seems to point directly towards the solution for the 1/3 bulb, and what makes this interesting is that the corresponding point on the cardioid falls at the base of the 1/4 bulb (not to mention that the line intersects the axes at easy rational numbers). However, when I zoom in on the 1/3 bulb, I see that the slope of the line is slightly at a different angle and does not intersect the point exactly, but perhaps this is a matter of precision error - and I have a hard time believing that this is a coincidence. Is there a relationship between the 1/4 and 1/3 bulbs by this line?

Here is the [Desmos graph I made](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lrcrxvmmtx), perhaps exploring it will yield further insight on what's going on (change *s* to change the parameter *t*, and *d* to change the length of the projected line).

[image: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lrcrxvmmtx]

**Edit:**

So I managed to figure out the exact answer for the center of the period 3 bulbs thanks to [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3.pdf) and added it to my Desmos graph, and so given the image below I'm thinking this whole thing might just be a coincidence... although to be fair I had a hard time understanding anything in that paper and so there is still some room for me to miss something important, and so if anyone could provide clarification on this connection I would be very appreciative!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a line through the individual two components of the cardioid"? And by "The blue line represents the vector between the two components"?

Comment: @joriki Thank you for this comment, I clarified what I meant in the question - what I meant with "two components" was the two parts of the equation of the boundary of the cardioid, _e^(it)/2_ and _-e^(2it)/4_, which are both points on a circle. If you move the slider on the Desmos graph I have linked, you'll see that both points on the line move in a circular motion. The orange dot is plotted when both points are added together, and the blue line is the vector between the two points